# Moving javascript files ROR 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

ok so I've got a couple of js files located in "views/relationships"….the original code is for 3.0…I'm on 3.1 and the javascript files are not working….how do I get these to works? here is the code for one of the files….

expounding on "not working":

the user clicks on a "unfollow" button, an ajax call takes place and runs on a function to do something, the "unfollow" button then changes to a "follow" button. That's what is supposed to happen...what actually...

UPDATE: turns out to be a simple prototype to jquery problem...

```
$("follow_form").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow'))%>")
$("followers").update('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

becomes...

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow'))%>")
$("#followers").html('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

Comment: Could you explain more about why they are "not working" such as: they are not rendering at all, they are being escaped too much (which was a bug in some RC versions of 3.1), etc.  The more detail the better

Answer (score 0):

Not all JavaScript files should be moved to `app/assets/javascripts`: only move files that are used to add functionality to your app (e.g. having tabbed menus with javascript). JavaScript templates rendering AJAX views (e.g. create.js.erb) should remain in the `app/views/users/` folder.

So to answer your question: the files you're talking about (based on the 2 lines included in your question) should remain where they are.